# Prevent item in list get deleted

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I assign the `onValue` to two variables in `initState`.

```
_boc.selectList(locationId).then((onValue) {
        list  = onValue;
        filterList = onValue;
        setState(() {});
      });
```

When it comes to this function, I clear the `filterList`, but the length of the list become 0.

```
Future<List<Obk>> getSuggestion(
      String search) async {
    if (search == "empty") return [];
    if (search == "error") throw Error();
    filterList.clear();
    print(list.length);   // this print 0
    });
     ...
 }
```

but if I remove this line `filterList = onValue;` , it will show the length of the `list`.
How to prevent the items in `list` from deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigned the same `List` Object to both `list` and `filteredList`. You can make a new list object using `List.from()`. So that your original `List` remains unchanged.

```
_boc.selectList(locationId).then((onValue) {
        list  = onValue;
        filterList = List.from(onValue);
        setState(() {});
      });
```

Now if you try to run your code and print the `list` length then you'll not get 0 after calling `filterList.clear()`.

```
Future<List<Obk>> getSuggestion(
      String search) async {
    if (search == "empty") return [];
    if (search == "error") throw Error();
    filterList.clear();
    print(list.length);   // this will print list length
    });
     ...
 }
```